# Slice assignment modifes original list

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a[:] = [] # and now a is also empty
```

Statement `a[:]` creates a copy of list `a` as I read, so if empty list `[]` is assigned to the copy then why original object is also modified?

Comment: Slice assignment != slicing. This is a feature, not a bug. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x = a[:]` makes `x` a new list containing the same values as `a`

`a[:] = x` makes the existing list `a` contain the same values as `x`

The behaviour of an expression changes when it switches sides of the equals.

Answer (score 4):

> Statement `a[:]` creates a copy of list `a` as I read

Except you're not reading, you're writing. Slice-assignment works differently in that it replaces the slice with the sequence.